# Determining reaction order from absorbance

Tags: concentration, reaction-order, rate-equation

> A reaction is initiated in a solution which contained a dissolved component. The transmittance was measured at $\pu{240 nm}$ in a $\pu{2.54 cm}$ long cell. At $t = 0$ the transmittance was $1$. $\varepsilon{}$ for the product is $\pu{470 dm^3 mol^{-1} mm^{-1}}$.
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{l|cccccccc}
> \hline
> t \text{[min]} & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 &  \infty \\
> \hline
> \text{transmittance} & 0.507 & 0.442 &  0.417 & 0.403 & 0.395 & 0.360  \\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> Determine the reaction order and rate constant

I am unsure if the way that I am solving this problem is the correct way of doing it. I begin by calculating the transmittance for the reactant(s) by taking the transmittance for the different times $t$ minus the transmittance for $t = \infty{}$. The way I am thinking about this is that at $t = \infty{}$ then all the reactants have become product which means that the transmittance at $t = \infty{}$ is the initial transmittance for the reactants (correct me if I'm wrong).

From this I get:

$$
\begin{array}{l|cccccccc}
\hline
%
t \text{[min]} & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 &  \infty \\
\hline
%
\text{transmittance} & 0.147 & 0.082 &  0.057 & 0.043 & 0.035 & 0  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Then I used Beer-Lambert's law to convert the transmittance to absorbance and then to concentration, getting:

$$
\begin{array}{l|cccccccc}
\hline
%
t \text{[min]} & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 &\\
\hline
%
\text{concentration} & 4.68*10^{-4} & 6.11*10^{-4} & 6.99*10^{-4} & 7.69*10^{-4} & 8.19*10^{-4}  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Plotting $t$ in seconds either against $\ln(c)$, or $1/c$ gives me that the reaction is of first order with a rate constant $k = \pu{5.62 \times 10^{-4} s^{-1}}$.

However, I also tried first converting the transmittance to absorbance, then calculating the absorbance for the reactants (by taking the last measured data minus the rest as for the transmittance) and then from that calculate the concentration. This then gives me that the reaction is of second order with a rate constant $k = \pu{32.9 M^{-1} s^{-1}}$.

Which way is the correct way of solving the problem? Or is both wrong? I find it confusing that the two methods give different answers depending on whether I use the transmittance or absorbance first..

Appreciate all the help!

**EDIT NEW ATTEMPT**

So, I think that this might be the way to do it and would appreciate if someone could correct me if I'm wrong.

I being by converting all the transmittance for the given product to the concentration of the product using Beer-Lambert's law.

$$
\begin{array}{l|cccccccc}
\hline
%
t \text{[min]} & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 &  \infty \\
\hline
%
\text{Concentration products} & 0.000166 & 0.000199 & 0.000214 & 0.000222 & 0.000227 & 0.00025  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Now, I calculate the concentration for the reactants by subtracting the concentration for t=$∞$ by the remaining concentrations to get:

$$
\begin{array}{l|cccccccc}
\hline
%
t \text{[min]} & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 &  \infty \\
\hline
%
\text{Concentration reactants} & 0.000084 & 0.000050 & 0.000036 & 0.000028 & 0.000023 & 0  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

I then plot the concentration as a first order and second order and get that the second order has a better fit. So the answer is that the reaction is of second order and the rate constant is $33$ M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$.

Does this make more sense than the first two methods?

Comment: I don't know if you know [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) including one of the later implemented (perhaps specific to chemistry.se) short hand of `\pu{}` as in `$t = \pu{32.5 s}$` (to yield $t = \pu{32.5 s}$).  It isn't [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (whose scope is not needed here on chemistry.se), but helpful to prevent line breaks in formulae, to retain formatting, and easing input in the body of questions, answers, comments.  (Not safe for titles of questions, though.)

Comment: If you have these plots at hand, why do you don't substantiate your question and add them to your question?

Comment: There are no unique answers to your question. It depends of some informations that are missing in the text.

First : Is the initial solution made of only one colored substance ? In other words, is the end product the result of the reaction or is it due to some other compound already present initially ?

Second : Do you know the extinction coefficients epsilon of the initial and of the final products ? Which one did you use to calculate the concentration ?

Comment: @Maurice I only know epsilon for the final products. Perhaps that justifies that I should convert the transmittance of the products to concentration **before** calculating the concentration of the reactants. Since I can't use epsilon later for the reactants.. if you understand what I mean

Comment: @Katara. Some information is still missing. 1) Is the initial mixture containing only one colored substance ? 2) How can you explain that the transmittance goes from 0.147 to zero, and simultaneously the concentration goes form $4.68$ to $8.19$ ? These data are contradictory !

Comment: @Maurice I wrote the question as given to me so I don't know more than what is said. 2) I didn't think of that.. but how would I solve this problem then, disregarding my two attempts.

Comment: @Maurice I have edited my question with another method that I think is more correct than the other two.. would truly appreciate it if you could have a look at it :)